# How can I enable the "Get-VM" Cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Is `Get-VM` native PowerShell cmdlet? I used `Get-Command` in PS, but could not able to find the cmdlet `Get-VM`.

Is this cmdlet specific to VMware? Is there some PowerShell command I am missing to get these hidden cmdlets?

Answer (score 3):

1. No. On Windows Server 2008 R2, you can use http://pshyperv.codeplex.com to manage Hyper-V using PowerShell cmdlets. On Windows Server 2012, when you enable Hyper-V role or on Windows 8, when you install Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT for Windows Server 2012), you get Hyper-V PowerShell cmdlets from Microsoft. Get-VM is a part of that.
2. Get-VM comes as a part of PowerCLI install for ESX management.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VMware PowerCLI installed, you can load the module/snapin:

```
Add-PSSnapin vmware.vimautomation.core
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet connection on your machine then you can install modules from online as and when needed.

I.e for Powercli which is where Get-VM comes from, instructions are here
https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2017/04/powercli-install-process-powershell-gallery.html

```
Find-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI
Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI
```

Once done then use to allow access to the commands:

```
Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI
```

Regards SQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-powershell

SQL Server Setup automatically configures PowerShell components.

If you are not on the server then

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

and repeat steps the same as PowerCli, you can choose a specific version of sql by using additional attribute of:
    -Version 21.0.17178